# Files synced via dropbox cannot be served with IIS because of file permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, dropbox, files

I'm running into the problem of using Dropbox and IIS.  I am using the Dropbox Folder Sync plugin to sync a folder outside the Dropbox folder.  They are synced into my `inetpub\root\downloads\` directory.

The problem is not that it doesn't sync.  The problem is that the files that get synced have no permissions attached to them.  I can't open any of them on IIS.

Initially the downloads were to be only PDFs but they don't open so I tried an .ASPX file and it fails to load as well.  Is there any way around this or another program I can use to sync files but allow them to be opened on an IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the folder has permissions to IIS user?
Try testing with giving all permissions to everyone on the folder and check if files are accessible by your application. Then start restricting the permissions.